# Is it possible to find the digital sum of first hundred decimal digits of $\sqrt2$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is it possible to find the digital sum of first hundred decimal digits of $\sqrt2$?

This question came to my mind when I was finding the digital sum i.e. the repeated sum of $1234^{5678}$ where I had to find $1234^{5678}$ (mod $9$) and then narrow down the remainder to $1$ digit.

Comment: sure. Are you looking for an elegant solution? You can do that by brute force by using a computer. You can actually simply use the digits from [here](http://apod.nasa.gov/htmltest/gifcity/sqrt2.1mil).

Comment: If this is for Project Euler (for example, problem 80) you should add that as a tag.

Comment: What is project Euler?

Comment: @Hyperbola : http://projecteuler.net/problem=80

Comment: If it's for Project Euler, it's off-limits; they have asked us not to discuss their questions here.

Comment: I didn't even know what Project Euler is until now.